# How can I connect to two different databases using MongoClient() in Pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I need to access two different collection each in their respective databases on the same server. For example i need the collection "dummy" in the database "dummy" and collection "foo" in database "bar". To connect to single database I have been using this code

```
client = MongoClient()
db = client.dummy()
collection = db['dummy']
```

But if I also add

```
db1 = client.bar
collection = db1['foo']
```

This is not working.

Comment: What do you mean by *it is not working*? Are you getting any error message? Also you have typo in there remove the parent from `db = client.dummy()` I think you meant `db = client.dummy`